# combine two plots into one graph

Tags: r

I am trying to draw pie charts with R. How can I combine the following pie charts into one graph?

```
data <- c(632,20,491,991,20)
names <- c("alpha","beta","gamma","delta","omega")
pie(data, names,col = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "cyan"),
main="PIE CHART 1")


data <- c(37376,41770,5210,5005,3947)
names <- c("alpha","beta","gamma","delta","omega")
pie(data, names,col = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "cyan"),
main="PIE CHART 2")
```

Comment: You can set `par(mfrow=c(1, 2))` to plot them together. It's a global option, so to close it you have to write again `par(mfrow=c(1, 1))`.

Comment: Creating pie charts is generally unwise, especially if you categories with similar proportions. Histograms and bar charts are much better visualization tools.

Answer (score 1):

```
par(mfrow=c(x,y)) # where x is number of rows and y is columns.
plot(...)
plot(...)
```

For more information regarding plotting multiple plots in one graphical window see: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html